# develop own WORKFLOW

Tags: workflow, jbpm

I m in an internship in an enterprise that wants to develop its own WORKFLOW, but they are only interested to "Time management" ..I am now understanding jBoss jbpm 
so what do you think about that? 
From where can I start in this project?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this question inviting opinion?

Surely the best platforms and tools for developing and hosting workflows are relatively dependent upon the enterprise in question, their ability to maintain and support such systems etc etc, aren't they?

For example, lots of larger enterprises invest heavily in Microsoft platforms, which also means they have more experience supporting those kinds of platforms and services. So, with this in mind, and in the interest of maintainability, supportability, I would choose Windows Workflow Foundation, which is incredibly comprehensive and extremely easy to integrate into Microsoft platforms.

If you were going to start looking into WWF then I can definitely recommend Pro WF, written by Bruce Bukovics and published by Apress (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-WF-Windows-Workflow-NET/dp/1430227214/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1289905106&sr=8-1)

If you are going the JBoss jBPM route, there's a whole site dedicated to it - including documentation, user and developer forums, and a wiki full of useful information. (http://jboss.org/jbpm)

First start by understanding the environment, the business processes and the way in which users interact with those processes. Only then can you really start designing workflows that will be of any use.